# Kivy Screen not appearing

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7

It was working fine. It would open window with 3 columns, with text I could enter. After adding some code, it suddenly stopped showing a screen, and it just says Username: in the terminal. I used a completely newly typed code, but still same result:

(I left out the importing from the top)

```
class ConnectPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 2  # used for our grid

        with open("prev_details.txt","r") as f:
            d = f.read().split(",")
            prev_ip = d[0]
            prev_port = d[1]
            prev_username = d[2]

        self.add_widget(Label(text='IP:'))  # widget #1, top left
        self.ip = TextInput(text=prev_ip, multiline=False)  # defining self.ip...
        self.add_widget(self.ip) # widget #2, top right

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Port:'))
        self.port = TextInput(text=prev_port, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.port)

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Username:'))
        self.username = TextInput(text=prev_username, multiline=False)
        self.add_widget(self.username)

        # add our button.
        self.join = Button(text="Join")
        self.join.bind(on_press=self.join_button)
        self.add_widget(Label())  # just take up the spot.
        self.add_widget(self.join)

    def join_button(self, instance):
        port = self.port.text
        ip = self.ip.text
        username = self.username.text
        with open("prev_details.txt","w") as f:
            f.write(f"{ip},{port},{username}")
        info = f"Joining {ip}:{port} as {username}"
        chat_app.info_page.update_info(info)
        chat_app.screen_manager.current = 'Info'
        Clock.schedule_once(self.connect, 1)

    def connect(self, _):

        port = int(self.port.text)
        ip = self.ip.text
        username = self.username.text

        if not socket_client.connect(ip, port, username, show_error):
            return

        chat_app.create_chat_page()
        chat_app.screen_manager.current = 'Chat'


class ChatPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1

        self.add_widget(Label(text='Fancy stuff here to come!!!', font_size=30))


class InfoPage(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        self.cols = 1

        self.message = Label(halign="center", valign="middle", font_size=30)

        self.message.bind(width=self.update_text_width)

        self.add_widget(self.message)

    def update_info(self, message):
        self.message.text = message

    def update_text_width(self, *_):
        self.message.text_size = (self.message.width * 0.9, None)


class Epicapp(App):
    def build(self):

        self.screen_manager = ScreenManager()

        self.connect_page = ConnectPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Connect')
        screen.add_widget(self.connect_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        # Info page
        self.info_page = InfoPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Info')
        screen.add_widget(self.info_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)

        return self.screen_manager

    def create_chat_page(self):
        self.chat_page = ChatPage()
        screen = Screen(name='Chat')
        screen.add_widget(self.chat_page)
        self.screen_manager.add_widget(screen)


def show_error(message):
    chat_app.info_page.update_info(message)
    chat_app.screen_manager.current = 'Info'
    Clock.schedule_once(sys.exit, 10)
```

This is the result (no screen)

```
Username: 
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved, i removed the `import socket_client.py` which is not shown in the code above. Now the `prev_details.txt` is making an error. `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'prev_details.txt'`